# Loading Amazon Redshift with a manifest, with an error in one file

Tags: amazon-redshift

When using the COPY command to load Amazon Redshift with a manifest, suppose one of the files contains an error.

Is there a way to just log the error for that file, but continue loading the other files?

Answer (score 1):

The **manifest file** indicates whether a file is **mandatory** and whether an error should be generated if a file is not found. ([Using a Manifest to Specify Data Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html))

The `COPY` command will retry if it cannot read a file. ([Errors When Reading Multiple Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-multiple-files.html))

The `COPY` command can specify a `MAXERRORS` parameter that **permits a certain number of errors** before the `COPY` command fails. ([MAXERROR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror))

When loading data from files, Amazon Redshift will report any errors in the `STL_LOAD_ERRORS` table. ([STL_LOAD_ERRORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html))

Answer (score 0):

As said above, the [maxerror](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror) property should satisfy the above requirement.

In addition, [copy-noload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-noload) property checks the validity of the data without loading. Running with NOLOAD parameter is much faster as it only parses the file